# Prevent Emacs from overwriting text

Tags: text-editing, overwrite

In this example:

[image]

If I add for example '0.5' where the cursor is, instead of adding '0.5' while moving the remaining text to the right, Emacs will delete the part '}{ckt1}' while adding '0.5'. Is it possible to avoid it so that when the cursor is in that position and I type 0.5 the result be just '[width=0.5]{ckt1}'?

Comment: What you're describing is not normal behaviour. It should do what you want by default. Can you reproduce the problem after starting emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit the `<insert>` key to toggle inserting vs overwriting.

`C-h k <insert>` tells you:

> `<insert>` runs the command `overwrite-mode`, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to `insertchar`, `insert`.
>
> `(overwrite-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle Overwrite mode.
>
> With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable Overwrite mode if `ARG` is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
>   the mode if `ARG` is omitted or `nil`.
>
> When Overwrite mode is enabled, printing characters typed in
>   replace existing text on a one-for-one basis, rather than pushing
>   it to the right.  At the end of a line, such characters extend
>   the line.  Before a tab, such characters insert until the tab is
>   filled in.  `M-x quoted-insert` still inserts characters in
>   overwrite mode; this is supposed to make it easier to insert
>   characters when necessary.

See the Emacs manual, node [Minor Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html).

Comment: This does not work for me. There is no change if I press `<insert>`, and `<Esc>-x overwrite-mode` does not work either. It keeps on overwriting. I recently changed to zsh, not sure if that could cause this problem..

Comment: I've rebound <insert> to another key in Xmodmap. My computer doesn't have an <insert> key. Yet somehow, emacs magically switches to overwrite mode every now and then. Something else is causing the bug.

Comment: @Zendel: What does `C-h w overwrite-mode` tell you? It should tell you of any keys that are bound to that command. If none are bound to it then bisect your init file to find out what code you load might be invoking the command.

Comment: It tells me that it's mapped to the <insert> key. A key that has been disabled in Xmodmap. I suppose there could be a bug in X11.

But really, it would be wonderful to just disable to behaviour in emacs period. Just tell emacs: NO!

Comment: It sounds like Emacs is still seeing that key. I can't speak to what Xmodmap does or should do. Hopefully someone else can speak to that.